# Tcp Hole Punching in c# using ReuseAddress

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcp, console-application

I am trying to accomplish Tcp hole punching with socket option as reuse address.

- First step- Run and tcp listener in server **S** with active open tcp port 8001.
- Second step- Run a Tcp socket with reuse address(method name is **enableReuseAddres(Socket sck)** mentioned below) in socket option on client **A**  which is behind the NAT on port 8001.
- Third step- Connect **A** => **S**.
- Fourth step- Send data from **A** => **S** and get confirm data from **S** => **A**.
- Fifth step- Get remote endpoint of **A** which is X.X.X.X:8001(External IP and Port of **A**).
- Sixth Step- Listen on a socket with port 8001(method name is **runServer** mentioned below),in client **A** with reuse address(method name is **enableReuseAddres(Socket sck)** mentioned below) in socket option.
  Disclaimer:- No error found and able to bind the same endpoint which is used to connect to the server **S** with the help of ReuseAddress and able to listen on the same port 8001.
  But when I try to check the port 8001 is opened  or closed I always get port is closed,of client **A**.

  ```
      public void runServer()
      {

          Socket sk = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, 
          SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
          enableReuseAddres(sk);
          sk.Bind(loclEP);
          sk.Listen(1);
          var connection_socket = sk.Accept();
          MessageBox.Show("Connected");

      }
      IPEndPoint loclEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 8001);
      public void enableReuseAddres(Socket sck)
      {
           sck.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, 
           SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
           sck.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, 
           SocketOptionName.KeepAlive, true);
      }
  ```

Comment: Question is confusing, you are using same port for client and host.  You mention the behind the NAT ports, but then talk about External IP, with same port.  This sounds like a NAT configuration issue.  But.... to really see what's happening run are Wireshark trace and confirm which side is having the issue.

Comment: Thank You for your comment. Basically I want TCP Hole Punching for that client A is try to connect  with the server S using port 8001. Now after connecting to the server I didn't close the socket and start listening from another socket with the same endpoint which was used for connecting S => A but when I am checking open port of A it is still closed . I want to be opened 8001 on A's    NAT

Comment: On the server, run a wireshark trace and post results here, we'll be able to understand this a bit more.

Comment: There is no issue with the server. client port is not opening

Comment: Have you considered using port forwarding with upnp instead? Take a look at  Open.NAT (https://github.com/lontivero/Open.NAT)